# JRadioButton java

Tags: java, user-interface, jradiobutton

I'm new to java GUI programming and while working on the project I'm getting the error cannot find symbol on my addActionListener for my JRadioButtons, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong since I didn't receive the same error when working with JButtons.

Here's my code:

```
public void SouthPanel() {

    JRadioButton greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green");
    JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");
    JRadioButton cyanButton = new JRadioButton("Cyan");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(greenButton);
    group.add(blueButton);
    group.add(cyanButton);

    greenButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    blueButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cyanButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    SouthPanel = new JPanel();
    add(greenButton);
    add(blueButton);
    add(cyanButton);

    add(SouthPanel);
    setVisible(true);
}
private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      String actionRadio = e.getActionCommand();

      if (actionRadio.equals("Green")) {
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
      }
      else if (actionRadio.equals("Blue")) {
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
      }
      else if (actionRadio.equals("Cyan")) {
        label.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
      }
    }
```

Comment: sorry this snippet was after i tried fooling around with the code a bit, i had the new keyword but was still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: ok then it should work, maybe take a look at the official [`RadioButtonDemo.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/RadioButtonDemoProject/src/components/RadioButtonDemo.java) or provide a complete example to test it.

Comment: ...thats the issue, it should work but its not working

Comment: Well a good way to start is to debug your `ActionListener`, is the `actionPerformed` method even called? if so maybe print `String actionRadio = e.getActionCommand();` to the console or just debug it with the debugger... if might not be set with the constructor of `JRadioButton` ..

Comment: Which `symbol` is the compiler saying it cannot find ?

Comment: @jr593 since he only provided the code of the method `SouthPanel` I assumed there is a class around all the code, but who knows :D

Comment: if you were to read my question first you would know where i am getting my error at, the program runs and compiles minus this snippet of code so i know the issue only resides here because ive done that part of the leg work that took me hours, 

\Desktop\ColorFactory.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
        blueButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
                                         ^

that is the error, better? it repeats for all 3 buttons

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the error "cannot find symbol" usually refers to a variable that can't be resolved by the compiler.

On what line does the error occur?

What seems a bit odd at first glance is following statement:

```
 SouthPanel = new JPanel();
```

and `add(SouthPanel);`

since SouthPanel is the name of your method and you didn't give a name to your SouthPanel (?) object.

Answer (score 0):

To use `getActionCommand()` on a `Button` or `RadioButton`, you should have previously set the `ActionCommand`

```
  button.setActionCommand(String val);
```

You'd be able to get it back when you make a call to:

```
  button.getActionCommand(); //This would return the string you previously set.
```

For a TextField, ActionCommand would give you the text in the TextField by default if you do not set it.

That's where you are probably missing the line.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance of the JPanel and inserted into SouthPanel class. How can it be done.

```
SouthPanel = new JPanel();
add(greenButton);
add(blueButton);
add(cyanButton);

add(SouthPanel);
setVisible(true);
```

Into where are you adding the buttons and adding the SouthPanel.! Please check this one.Seems the error is from here.3 buttons are added,for 3 times and error is shown for 3 times.right.Seems error is from here. Check here.

Answer (score 0):

See the complete code here.

```
 class SouthPanel extends JPanel {

 JLabel label = new JLabel("label");

  public SouthPanel() {

   JRadioButton greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green");
   JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");
   JRadioButton cyanButton = new JRadioButton("Cyan");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(greenButton);
    group.add(blueButton);
    group.add(cyanButton);

    greenButton.addActionListener((ActionListener) new 
    RadioButtonListener());
    blueButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cyanButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    JPanel SouthPanel = new JPanel();
    add(label);
    add(greenButton);
    add(blueButton);
     add(cyanButton);

    add(SouthPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(this);
      frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
   }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
     new SouthPanel();
    }

    private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     String actionRadio = e.getActionCommand();

      if (actionRadio.equals("Green")) {
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
      } else if (actionRadio.equals("Blue")) {
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
      } else if (actionRadio.equals("Cyan")) {
        label.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
      }
     }
    }
   }
```